# Working with GPS via libhardware on Android

Tags: android, c++, gps, android-source

In AOSP there is [libhardare library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/android-4.2.2_r1) which contains interface to the GPS driver - [gps.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/android-4.2.2_r1/include/hardware/gps.h). Using this interface you can get access to GPS driver on low level (C++), turn on GPS and get current location of the device.

On the Internet there are several projects, that use this GPS interface. For example, [this one created by kanru](https://gist.github.com/kanru/1568934). This code works almost perfectly - I could connect to GPS driver and get correct location.

But I ran into a problem. If you turn on GPS driver using kanru project and after awhile turn on GPS via standard method (in GUI), then C++ program will suddenly stop receive information from GPS driver. At the same time in GUI you can see that GPS is On and you can start Google Maps or any other GPS-related application and get your coordinates.

I tried to restart `GpsInterface`, turn off and on GPS driver via `hw_device_t` pointer, even restart whole C++ executable - no effect. 
After restart of the program GPS driver change status to `GPS_STATUS_ENGINE_ON` and then - silence.

Also I tried to change the order of actions. I turned on GPS in GUI, launched Google Maps and waited several minutes till I got my location. Then I started my C++ program. It successfully connected to GPS driver and started to get location data. Meanwhile GUI "lost" connection with GPS driver.

I tried to test my program on several devices with Android 4.2 and 5.1 and get same problem on the most of them. Only on Samsung S6 with Android 5.1 my program was able to work perfectly under all conditions.

It seems like on some devices GPS driver configured so that it can work with only one data consumer.

Perhaps someone faced a similar problem?